# How to implement sortable list of object in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have list of object that I want each item to be rendered with some renderer that include a delete and edit buttons with some text.

What is the best way to make the list of object re-order-able in drag/drop fashion so the user can drag on item on top of another to change the order of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, just use a List, or DataGrid, with an itemRenderer that displays the buttons.  Look into the [DragEnabled](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#dragEnabled), [DragMoveEnabled](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#dragMoveEnabled), and [DropEnabled](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#dropEnabled) properties for the click and drag sorting.

Look into using [itemEditors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/celleditor_8.html) for the edit functionality.

At the risk of sounding self indulgent, our [DataSorter](http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=7) component is designed for sorting lists.  It is modeled after the Netflix movie queue / YouTube Playlist editor, but can be easily modified or extended as needed.  Free developer editions are available from the web site and you can check out our [API Explorer](http://www.flextras.com/DataSorter/Samples/CodeGenerator/#) sample.